# 'Load failed' error when trying to create a function in AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

is anybody getting a 'load failed' error when hitting the 'create function button ?
I am using my root account

thank you all very much!
[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Goa8C.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Goa8C.png)

- I tried with another user to which I gave lambda rights
- I tried all other setting options

Comment: That should not be happening. Since you are using the root user, it is not permission-related. You could try using a different browser since the error might be on your end. For another experiment, you could pre-create an IAM Role in the IAM console -- create it for use with AWS Lambda. Then, when creating the Lambda function you "Use an existing role" instead of "Create a new role". This will help isolate what is causing the problem.

Comment: Is your account new? Have you checked your payment area for any issues related to it? Sometimes aws doesn't let you create stuff and you get strange messages(I got in the past) and it turned out to be an issue with my payment method. And once that was resolved, I had to open a ticket requesting permissions to be granted to create stuff.